# How to access a javascript object value whose key is also an object (Azure AD SSO, Single grant flow)

Tags: javascript, object, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, msal.js

Currently I am working on implementing Azure AD SSO for my single page app and I am stuck in a situation where I want to retreive the token value returned by the Azure AD and is stored in the localstorage.The problem is with the structure of the object.The object has the following structure:

```
TokenObj = {
{"authority":"https://authority","clientID":"aabbc","securityId":"aadds"}: {"accessToken","aabbcc","idToken","aabbc","expiresIn":15364364634363}

msal.token_id:"aabbaabbaa",

msal.client.info: "aassssaass"
}
```

I want to access the value for expiresIn.

Thank you in advance for reading this and trying to help.

Comment: That's not a valid object. Keys can only be strings (numbers are converted to strings).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't using `acquireTokenSilent`? It is not recommended to read the MSAL.js values directly from local/session storage, as they are considered implementation details and could change (and break your code) without warning.

The keys/values of these entries are stringified objects, so you would need to use JSON.parse/JSON.stringify to build the keys or parse the values.